# Find all elements with a matching background

Tags: jquery, background-color

I would like to:

1. Scan through all divs that are children within an ID container called "container"
2. Find divs that have a background colour of a certain colour (currently defined in a variable, which we can call "currentColor")
3. Replace the background colour of each of those

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own?

Comment: Yes. We need some demo also. Your question is not clear

Comment: Any work or results you have reached? Any non-succesful tries you've made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Scan through all divs that are children within an ID container called "container"

```
$('#container div').each(function(){
    console.log(this)
});
```

> Find divs that have a background colour of a certain colour (currently defined in a variable, which we can call "currentColor")

```
$('#container div').filter(function(){
    return $(this).css('background-color') == currentColor ; 
});
```

> Replace the background colour of each of those

```
$('#container div').filter(function(){
    return $(this).css('background-color') == currentColor ;
}).css('background-color', 'newcolor');
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Really elegant code too. Thank you Miind.